# How can I make a pop over controller dismissible by tapping elsewhere on the screen?

Tags: ios, swift, uipopovercontroller

I just encountered a very strange situation. I added a popover segue on the storyboard, set its anchor, ran the app, and performed the segue. I can dismiss the popover controller by tapping elsewhere.

However, if I show a popover controller using code:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("VC")
vc.modalInPopover = true
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .Popover

vc.popoverPresentationController!.sourceRect = CGRectMake(100, 100, 0, 0)
vc.popoverPresentationController?.sourceView = self.view

self.presentVC(vc)
```

I can't dismiss the popover controller by tapping elsewhere!

What have I done differently from the segue method? Why is the behaviour different? How can I get it to work the way the segue method worked? i.e. the user can dismiss the popover by tapping elsewhere.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1619312-modalinpopover?language=objc

Comment: @Shubhank Oh I see now! When I found this property, I only saw the summary part of the docs: `A Boolean value indicating whether the view controller should be presented modally by a popover` and didn't read the description part. Now I understand! Thank you!